# Visio - How to access a shape parent's custom property?

Tags: visio

I have grouped 3 shapes (simple square boxes) together.  In each of those shapes, I would like to add a field that will display the value of a custom property defined in the "parent" shape (ie: the group).

I know that if the property was directly bounded to the shape I was adding the field to, the formula for that field would simply be: "=prop.MyProperty".

I've looked for something like: "=parent.prop.MyProperty" with luck.  Any clue?

Comment: Also read more about [syntax of cells references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/about-cell-references)

Answer (score 1):

Although there nothing like "parent", you can use shape id directly. You need to find the ID (NNN) of the parent shape (i.e. of the group shape), and then use it in the child shape using the syntax like this:

```
=Sheet.NNN!Prop.MyProperty
```

The ID of the shape can be found using drawing explorer window (it displays shapes with ids), or "Shape Name" button on the "Developer" tab, ID() shape sheet function on the group (parent) shape, or shape.ID property VBA code.

Comment: actually in VBA there is a parent property, but it's not available as function in the shapesheet. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VBA there is a Parent property.
IF VSOShp1 contains VSOShp2 and VSOShp2
Debug.Print VSOShp2.Parent
will show the name of the parent VSOShp1.
Debug.Print VSOShp2.Parent.ID
will show the sheet id of VSOShp1.
John...